# Why isnt my BlueGiga BLE113 being discovered?

Tags: bluetooth, bluegiga

I have a BLE113 chip wired like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWj57.jpg

I've measured the voltage through the wires to make sure that power is going into the BLE113 board, and a constant input of 3.3V is (which is what is required).

I flashed the chip using the BGDemo project found on Bluegiga's website, and on http://edisonthk.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/getting-started-with-developing-bluetooth-4-0-le-and-android-with-ble112-bluetooth-module/

The bgdemo script:

```
dim addr(6)

# Boot Event listener
event system_boot(major ,minor ,patch ,build ,ll_version ,protocol_version ,hw )

    #Get local BT address
    call system_address_get( )(addr(0:6))

    # Write BT address to DI service serial number string
    call attributes_write(xgatt_dis_2a25,0,6,addr(0:5))

    #set to advertising mode
    call gap_set_mode(gap_general_discoverable,gap_undirected_connectable)

    #set bondable mode
    call sm_set_bondable_mode(1)

end

# Disconnection event listener
event connection_disconnected(handle,result)
    #connection disconnected, continue advertising
    call gap_set_mode(gap_general_discoverable,gap_undirected_connectable)
end
```

No errors came up through bgbuild. And I mark the chip as discoverable and connectable yet none of my bluetooth devices are discovering the chip, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting BlueGiga support about this, they responded with a solution... The BGDemo is unfortunately not set up properly, however when I update my board with the Heart Rate Demo, for example, It is fully discoverable.

When connected to the LightBlue app for iPhones with BLE, all simulated heart information is received as well.

However, the only differences in the Heart Rate demo compared to the BGDemo is the code, all of the project files are virtually the same. Reminding me: BG Support explained that addr should be called with start and length, not start and end like how i was using it when i called the following:

```
call attributes_write(xgatt_dis_2a25,0,6,addr(0:5))
```

As such, it should be addr(0:6) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add  `<device type="ble113" />`  to `project.xml` (or `project.bgproj`)?

See [Bluegiga's knowledge bas](https://bluegiga.zendesk.com/entries/24781536--HOW-TO-Convert-a-BLE112-project-to-a-BLE113-project)e article for more information. But in general, to convert a BLE112 project (like bgdemo) to a BLE113 project:

- Add  `<device type="ble113" />`  to project.xml (or project.bgproj)
- Disable/remove references to USB from hardware.xml and BGScript source
- Use hardware I2C pins instead of P1_6 and P1_7 if I2C is used

I don't think the last two bullets apply, so check to make sure you have the correct device type in your project file (most likely named `project.bgproj`).

Example:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <project>
      <gatt in="gatt.xml" />
      <hardware in="hardware.xml" />    
      <script in="bgdemo.bgs" />
      <image out="out.hex" />
      <device type="ble113" />
      <boot fw="bootuart" />     
  </project>
```

Comment: The CCDebugger would have sent back an error to bgbuild if i had not set the device type to ble113.

In the project file, the device is in fact set to ble113 and there are no references to the USB setup.

How do I check if the chip is using l2c?

Comment: From the link in the answer: Hardware differences: USB vs. I2C
From a hardware perspective, the BLE112's two USB data pins (USB+ and USB-) have been swapped out for I2C pins (SDA and SCL). This means that the P1_6 and P1_7 pins required for the BLE112's software I2C should not be used for that purpose, but instead you should use the dedicated hardware I2C pins. No changes to the BGScript or BGAPI commands are necessary to take advantage of this difference; it will be handled automatically.

Comment: Also, have you tried using the "find_me" project rather than the "bgdemo" project?